# Malloc a 2D int array in C++ in one expression

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, malloc, multidimensional-array

Now, I need to save a class to a binary file and the problem I ran into when trying to implement this was that the class had members that were actually pointers, so when writing the class to file it only wrote those pointers, not the actual data that the pointers were pointing to.

So what I did was I used malloc() to allocate memory directly when declaring the members within the class. I know that isn't a good thing to do, but I really need to be able to save this class to a binary file.

I could do this easily with char arrays (1 dimensional), but I also have a single 2D int array, and I just can't figure out how to make it allocate enough memory for both dimensions (I know the dimension sizes beforehand). What should I do?

Maybe there's a way to declare static arrays, since I know their sizes beforehand, and then somehow replace them in memory with new ones? I don't know if I can do that, and I don't want to replace elements one by one.

Note: I need the variables to be pointers, because I want to be able to replace their contents later on, instead of having to replace the elements one by one.

Comment: Your serialization seems strange.

Comment: (I know the dimension sizes beforehand). What should I do? You should `std::array<std::array<int, M>, N>` if your compiler supports C++11 or `std::vector<std::vector<int>> v(N, std::vector<int>(M))` if it doesn't.

Comment: std::vector< std::vector<int> > tiles(20, std::vector<int>(15)); doesn't work for me. the compiler throws an error "expected identifier before numeric constant".

Comment: @Fabis - What compiler are you using? What is the exact code you're trying to compile? It does need you to `#include <vector>`

Comment: CodeBlocks (GNU GCC). And that is the exact code I'm compiling, nothing else is broken in the code, because when I remove this, everything compiles.

Comment: `#include <vector>` `int main() { std::vector< std::vector<int> > tiles(20, std::vector<int>(15)); }`  This code compiles correctly and has to compile correctly for the compiler you're using.  Otherwise you're doing something wrong.